# Foreach inside while

Tags: php

I have extracted all the domains I have from my database, I would like to draw all comments to the domains that are added in the database.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT domain_name, id_view FROM domain GROUP BY domain_name ORDER BY domain_name");
$comment = $mysqli->query("SELECT domain_name, id_view, comment FROM domain_comment");
$id_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment)) {
    $id_array[] = $row['comment'];
    $id_array[] = $row['id_view'];
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{

    $section = $row['id_view'];
          foreach ($id_array as $sectionname) {
            if ($sectionname == $section) {
                echo $sectionname;
            }
          }
}
```

The data it receives is VIEW ID and not Comment, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
When he gives the Select query:

```
$comment = $mysqli->query("SELECT comment FROM domain_comment INNER JOIN domain ON domain_comment.id_view = domain.id_view");
```

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($comment))
        {
          echo $row2['comment'];
        }
```

}

It prints all the comments at the first domain.

The result I have:
[image: The result I have]

The result he wants:
[image: The result he wants]

Comment: From what I see,  the two tables should have a relationship (foreign key). Instead of running two separate queries

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale - edited post.

Answer (score 0):

this part

```
 $id_array[] = $row['comment'];
$id_array[] = $row['id_view'];
```

What are you trying to do?

inserting comment in the id array? in this case the id_array will have one comment and one id, i dont think this is what you want. and second loop definitely us $row2 it is safer and wont mix up. inner join the quickest way.you are already there i think.

try removing the line

```
 $id_array[] = $row['comment'];
```

and check.

for innerjoin you can try to innerjoin on two keys i.e also domain.

```
    $comment = $mysqli->query("SELECT comment FROM domain_comment INNER JOIN domain ON domain_comment.id_view = domain.id_view and domain_comment.domain_name = domain.domain_name");
```

Comment: I added screenshots of what it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment)) {
    $id_array[$row['id_view']]['comments'][] = $row['comment'];
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $id_array[$row['id_view']]['data'] = $row;
}
```

You can try this solution after just dump `$id_array` in this case it would be much more easier to handle data.